# Overriding Third Party Adminhtml Controller

Tags: admin, adminhtml, overrides, extend

I can't override another third party module:

I tried either of these but no success:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <thirdparty>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_filedownloads before="ThirdParty_Adminhtml">My_FileDownloads_Adminhtml</my_filedownloads>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </thirdparty>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_filedownloads before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_FileDownloads_Adminhtml</my_filedownloads>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_filedownloads before="ThirdParty_Adminhtml">My_FileDownloads_Adminhtml</my_filedownloads>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**Explanation:** You add your router to the same front name as the other module (`adminhtml`) but your namespace should be used before the one of the other module (`ThirdParty_Adminhtml`)

So in the end, the priority is:

1. MyFileDownloads_Adminhtml
2. ThirdParty_Adminhtml
3. Mage_Adminhtml

(actually with other modules in between that you don't care about because they will contain different controllers)

Comment: Hey your above answer is not usefull.For third part overide you will use third party module name instead <Adminhtml>

Comment: No you don't use the module name but the name of the router. And if the third party module added a controller to the adminhtml router, which is how I understand the question, this is `adminhtml`.

Comment: Hi I have practically implemented on Dicove theme

Comment: I see, in your case the router was `banner7`. The question doesn't state it explicitly but that OP tried to use `before="Mage_Adminhtml"` suggests that it is about an Adminhtml controller within the `adminhtml`  router of  the third party module.

Comment: Brother I have overide the Adminhtml controller not frontend controller.For you knowledge when we  code under <admin><router>  ....  it means we are overideing Adminhtml controller.

Comment: <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Sourav_Jain before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sourav_Jain_Adminhtml</Sourav_Jain>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
   
   
   <banner7>
    <args>
     <modules>
      <Sourav_Jain before="Magentothem_Banner7">Sourav_Jain</Sourav_Jain>
     </modules>
    </args>
   </banner7>
   
   
   
        </routers>
    </admin>

Answer (score 0):

```
   
       <banner7>
                <args>
                    <modulesv
                        <Sourav_Jain before="Magentothem_Banner7">Sourav_Jain</Sourav_Jain>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </banner7>
```

I have override the thirs party extension(Magentothem_Banner7) controller using above code. Magentothem_Banner7 this is third extenson and Sourav_Jain is my custom module